# PHP how to include composer autoload in Class file

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader

I got difficult to include composer autoload in Class file, it not working on `require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');`

```
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

class Test {

    function X()
    { ... }

}
```

What is the proper way to load multiple include files in a class?

Comment: Can't tell from your code, but usually you have to run the composer file <b>once in the command line</b> aka terminal when you install a framework.

Comment: Your asking an OOP way to to require files right ?

Comment: If you're new, please read and learn. Good place to start is to read the [Composer Basic Usage](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md) guide.

Comment: @vladawtsu, yes, I am studying something like `spl_autoload`

Comment: The whole purpose of using the [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) is to remove the need of manually including all the needed files. All you have to do is to include `vendor/autoload.php` once, in the script that provides the entry point of your application.

Answer (score 7):

If you (correctly) use composer you need do add only the vendor autoload file. Then add the other dependency via composer vendor library or add custom path (composer do the rest for you).

As example, more simply:

1. start in an empty directory
2. launch the command:

> php composer.phar init

3. Add the dependency of the library in the composer.json files (if you don't add it in the init process) with the command (suggested by the [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer) site)

> composer require phpmailer/phpmailer

4. Then your class should be like:

   ```
   require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

   class Test {

   function X()
   { ... }

   }
   ```

Hope this help

Answer (score -3):

I think you want something like this

```
class Loader
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
        require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
    }
}

$loader = new Loader();
```

just add some function as you want

tell me if this help you ... goodluck

Comment: This is a terrible pattern,. Beyond the inefficiency of the code, you'll kill your memory.